# Objective-c Sorting NSArray with alphanumeric strings in correct order

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings that contain numbers i.e. `Shift 1 RT9909` I sort the array as follows:

```
NSSet *forms = dataObject.rtForms;

NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [forms sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor]];
```

This works fine while the number of elements is under 10. After this point `Shift 10 RT9909` is placed in front `Shift 2 RT9909`.

So my question is how can I sort the array so that `Shift 10 RT9909` would follow `Shift 9 RT9909`

Comment: You will have to parse the string into values and sort by those values. There is no way around it. Or add leading zeros to your strings.

Comment: `NSArray *sorted = [forms sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(rtFormClass _Nonnull form1, rtFormClass * _Nonnull form2) { return [form1.type compare:form2.type options:NSNumericSearch];`? Use `NSNumericSearch` to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Larme suggested you need to use `Comparator` with `NSNumericSearch`, you can also combined with `NSSortDescriptor`

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
NSArray *sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Perfect, works a treat. Thank you

Comment: @jampez77 Welcome mate :)